# Use NaN for values that can't be cast using astype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a very large Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "U", "3.4"]})
>>> d
     a
0    1
1    U
2  3.4
```

Currently the column is set as an `object`:

```
>>> d.dtypes
a    object
dtype: object
```

I'd like to convert this column to float so that I can use `groupby()` and compute the mean. When I try it using `astype` I correctly get an error because of the string that can't be cast to float:

```
>>> d.a.astype(float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'U'
```

What I'd like to do is to cast all the elements to float, and then replace the ones that can't be cast by NaNs.

How can I do this?

I tried setting `raise_on_error`, but it doesn't work, the `dtype` is still `object`.

```
>>> d.a.astype(float, raise_on_error=False)
0      1
1      U
2    3.4
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and specify `errors='coerce'` to force strings that can't be parsed to a numeric value to become `NaN`:

```
>>> pd.to_numeric(d['a'], errors='coerce')
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.4
Name: a, dtype: float64
```