# In a string dataframe, How to check casting capability into a float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

I have a manual dataset where a column `TPI_kW` is supposed to have float values.
It is stored into a dataframe 'df_data'.

I try to cast `TPI_kW` with :

```
df_data[`TPI_kW`] = df_data[`TPI_kW`].astype(float)
```

i got this error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '*94'
```

this value is indeed in my column :

```
df_data[df_data['TPI_kW'] == '*94']['TPI_kW']

Out[5]: 
Timestamp
2021-01-14 18:00:00    *94
Name: TPI_kW, dtype: object
```

If this kind of error is recurrent, it's very boring to search for all of them..

I'm wondering if there is a way to check (efficiently) casting capability into a float, before raising an error. And maybe replace the error value with `np.nan` ?

Best regards !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771807/use-nan-for-values-that-cant-be-cast-using-astype

Comment: depends on what you want to do if casting isn't possible. but in general it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission -> `try/except`

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @enke good answer, but when code is extraced from other threads, they should be referenced